# How to disable mdadm when running hardware RAID

Tags: debian, mdadm, hardware-raid

My server Dell R210 runs a Debian squeeze with hardware RAID1 (H200) preconfigured. But I notice that there is mdadm running. Sometimes in backup, or in OS upgrade (to Debian 6.0.4), I have messages like this:

```
W: mdadm: /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf defines no arrays.
W: mdadm: no arrays defined in configuration file.
```

Are they safe to ignore? How do I disable mdadm? Just a `/etc/init.d/mdadm stop`, a bit of observation then `apt-get remove mdadm`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message you have about mdadm.conf don't garanties you don't have arrays. The configuration file rarely contains any array.

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

If you see no array, you can remove the mdadm package. Or leave it, no problem.

```
apt-get purge mdadm
```

Comment: `cat /proc/mdstat` says: `Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
unused devices: <none>`. I would like to remove it because I think the monitoring slows down the machine.

Comment: There is no slowdown unless you can prove it.

Comment: @jørgensen There is an unused process running in background. It *should* cost something.